# Can Minuteman LGM-30 booster be used to launch commercial satellites?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, icbm

The LGM-30 Minuteman is the only land based ICBM in the US strategic arsenal. Gradually these missiles will have to be retired. My question is, can they be used to launch commercial satellites into LEO? What is the highest orbit they can achieve?

Comment: See [Minotaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_(rocket_family))

Comment: They use Minuteman II and Peacekeeper (motors). My question is about Minuteman III. With minimum modifications to the existing rocket.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://gutenberg.us/articles/lgm-30_minuteman#Satellite_launching_role) at the Gutenberg Self-Publishing Press, the LGM-30 Minuteman III has been considered for launching satellites. It also states that Orbital Sciences currently already modifies the Minuteman series 
for use in the Minotaur launch vehicle (although it seems this is the Minuteman II).

It looks like most of the necessary specifications are provided [here](http://www.astronautix.com/lvs/mineman3.htm), so I will try and simulate a launch to get an idea of what kind of payloads could be lifted to LEO.

Comment: Great, I really love the enthusiasm around this community!

Comment: One question, I noticed in the spec. article you mentioned: "Success Rate: 96.32%" That is pretty high success rate in this field, right? But I guess there have not been that many launches.

Comment: Definitely a weird spec since the vehicle was never used as intended. They must be quoting test launches -- I would comment on the relative success compared to other launchers but I can't say off the top of my head. There should be a question on here related to that success rate across various LVs.

Comment: Check this one out: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/8566/12038

Comment: Btw, here is a video of a test launch in the pacific testing range: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDL_pIPScSI . Basically they take a random missile from a silo in the country and bring it to Wanderberg AFB, replace the warheads with test MRVs and launch it at an atoll in the West Pacific. The precision and accuracy of this thing is remarkable, and a bit scary to be honest.

Comment: Hard not to like everything rocketry-related, but would be nice to see these launching satellites into orbit instead of testing warhead targeting. And hopefully the next rocket video I watch includes a landing!

Comment: As a note, the Gutenberg article is a copy of an old (pre-March 2015?) version of the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGM-30_Minuteman

Comment: The Astronautix success rate seems to be pretty simply (successful launches) / (total launches), including all flight tests - that page reports ten failures & all were testing/development launches