# How many ICBMs could have been successfully launched?

Tags: failure, icbm

Did the United States or USSR ever publicly state their estimates for what percentage of their ICBM fleets would launch successfully when the president gave the order? Answers to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/what-is-the-success-failure-ratio-of-space-bound-rockets) suggest that 8% of all uncrewed rocket launches have been failures. I figure the ICBM rate could have been higher for two reasons:

1. The 8% calculation does not include launch delays. For an ICBM, a launch delay would be a form of mission failure.
2. ICBMs were constantly monitored by the launch crews, but they did not have the same level of scrutiny and pre-mission attention of planned launches, where the timing of the launch is known in advance.

So are there estimates of how many ICBMs would have made it to their targets when the president gave the order?

Comment: Not sure this is really on topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about missile technology/defense not space

Comment: 1) It is still about space rocketry 2) we have currently probably no site for the question (maybe https://engineering.stackexchange.com ). My suggestion would be to answer it, but restrict the topic to the rocketry part (particularly any politics / military should be left out).

Comment: there is of course plenty of historical overlap between "weapons" rockets and "space exploration" rockets so there can potentially be a question about an ICBM that is on topic. But I don;t think this one is one of those.

Comment: It fits within the scope of the [tag:icbm] tag, so it's on-topic.  However, I don't think it's worth re-opening, as I don't think you'll get a different answer than the previous question.  (1) Weapons technology is classified information.  (2) The military has more rockets, but they sit in silos.  NASA *launches* far more rockets than the military.  (3) Whatever estimates the military has is likely to be derived from NASA's experience, which is reported in the previous question.